# Makefile executed unexpected behavior

Tags: makefile, g++, gnu-make

I used the following Makefile to compile C++ files but some unexpected behavior happened. The environment is MacOS X Mojave. The Makefile is as:

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
RM=rm -f

all: clean sort_test ds_test

sort_test: data_structure sort .sort_test.o .sort_test

.sort_test: sort_test.o sort.o ds.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o sort_test sort_test.o sort.o ds.o

.sort_test.o: sort_test.cpp ../include/io.hpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o sort_test.o sort_test.cpp

sort: ../include/sort.hpp ../include/data_structure.hpp ../src/sort.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o sort.o ../src/sort.cpp

data_structure: ../include/data_structure.hpp ../src/data_structure.cpp ../include/io.hpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o ds.o ../src/data_structure.cpp

ds_test: data_structure .ds_test.o .ds_test

.ds_test: ds.o ds_test.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o ds_test ds.o ds_test.o

.ds_test.o: ds_test.cpp ../include/io.hpp ../include/data_structure.hpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o ds_test.o ds_test.cpp

clean:
        $(RM) *.o sort_test ds_test
```

When I run "make ds_test" in the same directory, something weird happens:

```
g++ -std=c++11   -c -o ds_test.o ds_test.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c -o ds.o ../src/data_structure.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c -o ds_test.o ds_test.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -o ds_test ds.o ds_test.o
gcc   ds_test.o data_structure .ds_test.o .ds_test   -o ds_test
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'data_structure'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '.ds_test.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '.ds_test'
make: *** [ds_test] Error 1
```

The first and fifth line in this output are never expected for command "make ds_test" since it should only invoke "data_structure", ".ds_test.o" and ".ds_test".
Anybody, please explain why these extra unexpected behaviors would happen and how to avoid it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Makefile is a bit weird. The basic make rules are something like:

```
file-to-build: files-it-depends-on
    command-to-build
```

While you wrote things like:

```
.ds_test: ds.o ds_test.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o ds_test ds.o ds_test.o
```

where the target is not the file produced by the recipe. Moreover, you rename things,  without the proper extensions (`data_structure` versus `ds.o`). And finally you use different names for the same thing (again `data_structure` versus `ds.o`). If you are beginning with C++ and make, you should probably avoid all these fancy things.

The main reason why your Makefile fails is because make is trying to build a file named `ds_test` (this what you ask for when typing `make ds_test`). And make knows a lot of ways to build files. In this specific case it uses its default rule which consists in using `$(CC)` to link together `ds_test.o` and all other files `ds_test` depends on, that is, `data_structure`, `.ds_test.o` and `.ds_test`.

If you are new to make I suggest that you first stick with its most fundamental principles. Something like:

```
CC       := gcc
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
RM       := rm -f

.PHONY: all clean

all: clean sort_test ds_test

sort_test: sort_test.o sort.o data_structure.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

sort_test.o: sort_test.cpp ../include/io.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

sort.o: ../src/sort.cpp ../include/sort.hpp ../include/data_structure.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

data_structure.o: ../src/data_structure.cpp ../include/data_structure.hpp ../include/io.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

ds_test: data_structure.o ds_test.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

ds_test.o: ds_test.cpp ../include/io.hpp ../include/data_structure.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.o sort_test ds_test
```

Explanations:

- `$@`, `$<`and `$^` are [make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) that expand respectively as the target, the first prerequisite and the list of all prerequisites. They are not just convenient, they are much less error prone than retyping the same file names in targets, prerequisites and recipes.
- `.PHONY` is a [special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) with which you signal to make which targets are not real files.

**EDIT**: added `LDLIBS` to link C++ object files with `gcc` and an alternate linking rule.

Note: as make is really smart and knows by default how to compile and link C++ files, you could simplify all this. Especially if you also use the [`VPATH` make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search):

```
CC       := gcc
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDLIBS   := -lstdc++
RM       := rm -f
EXEC     := sort_test ds_test

.PHONY: all clean

all: clean sort_test ds_test

VPATH    := ../src:../include

sort_test.o: io.hpp
sort.o: sort.hpp data_structure.hpp
data_structure.o: data_structure.hpp io.hpp
ds_test.o: io.hpp data_structure.hpp

sort_test: sort_test.o sort.o data_structure.o
ds_test: data_structure.o ds_test.o

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(EXEC)
```

Note: as make will use `gcc` to link, we must add `-lstdc++` to the linker flags (`LDLIBS`). Another option is to specify the linking rule instead of letting make use the default:

```
$(EXEC):
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Note that, in this last case, the rule specifying of the prerequisites and the rule specifying the recipe are different.

Comment: Hi Renaud, this answer helped me a lot, thank you very much! BTW, it seems like for "sort_test" & "ds_test", I have to manually add the command to use $(CXX), otherwise they would use gcc by default to link *.o files, which causes some linking troubles.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer and added two possibilities to fix this.